# What is pp in books?

Tags: terminology

I have a bibliographical reference:

> [Author] [book name]-5th ed.,pp.3-6,ch.3.

What does the "pp" stand for? I don't recognize this abbreviation.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Literature SE. Please see [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14533/usage-of-p-versus-pp-versus-pg-to-denote-page-numbers-and-page-ranges#14539) on English SE.

Answer (score 11):

The "pp" refers to a page range, e.g. "pp. 3-6" means page three through page six.

I'm not entirely sure what citation style you're using, but this convention is used in the [MLA citation style](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/06/), as well as some other citation styles that I can't remember off the top of my head.

LiteratureSE user [Aethelbald](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/4274/aethelbald) has suggested that:

> pp stands for the Latin [**pari
>   passu**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pari_passu) meaning
>   side-by-side or at-the-same-rate or on-an-equal-footing... here it
>   means equally and throughout pages 3 thru 6.

**Other contributors, however, disagree**. [Kevin](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/997/kevin) notes that:

> Wiktionary also lists "p." as meaning "page," singular, and
>   specifically describes "pp." as the plural of "p." This is obviously
>   not a
>   [productive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics))
>   pluralization method

and [hobbs](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/965/hobbs) adds that:

> there are a few cases, in Latin-derived abbreviations, where a plural
>   is made by doubling the last letter. "MS." => "MSS." (manuscript/s),
>   "op." => "opp." (opus/opera). This is one of those, since "page" has
>   its origin in "pagina".

Comment: Anyone know why exactly it's called "pp"? Does it stand for something?

Comment: @MCMastery at least per [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pp.), it doesn't seem to have a meaning, just a way to distinguish it from `p.`, to indicate plural

Comment: @Gallifreyan: Wiktionary also lists "p." as meaning "page," singular, and specifically describes "pp." as the plural of "p."  This is obviously not a [productive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics)) pluralization method.

Comment: @MCMastery there are a few cases, in Latin-derived abbreviations, where a plural is made by doubling the last letter. "MS." => "MSS." (manuscript/s), "op." => "opp." (opus/opera). This is one of those, since "page" has its origin in "pagina".

Comment: Do you have a credible source for the claim that "pp" stands for the Latin phrase *pari passu*?

Answer (score -3):

**pp** stands for the Latin [**pari passu**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pari_passu) meaning side-by-side or at-the-same-rate or on-an-equal-footing.  In this case, Citations has already given the correct answer and I'm just filling in.

Comment: In that case, you should either edit Citation's post with the relevant information or comment on his post. Not post a new answer.

Comment: That's not exactly intuitive but thanks, I'll bear  it in mind.

Comment: How is "pari passu" relevant to bibliographical references? OK, it's a possible meaning of the abbreviation "pp", but surely not the correct meaning in this context?

Comment: Rand, here it means equally and throughout pages 3 thru 6.

Comment: I've taken up @corsiKa's suggestion and edited Citation's post to include the information from your answer. It's entirely up to you, but you might now like to delete your answer. I have a feeling you earn a site badge for doing so! :-)